# Filter divs with jQuery

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

i'm trying to develop a webpart under sharepoint that filters divs, here's what i did

```
function FilterDivs() {
    $('div.filters').find('input:checkbox').click(function () {
        $('.items> div').hide();
        $('div.filters').find('input:checked').each(function () {
            $('.items> div.' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();
        });
    });
}
```

this function is working fine with static data i.e with defined filters (checkboxs) and defined items :
Example :

```
 <div id="vcf-theme"  class="Filters">
            <div class="title">Mathematics</div>
            <div class="vcf-allInput">
            <p class="vcfcb-theme">
                    <input id="test3" rel="Newcontracts" type="checkbox">
                    <label for="test3">New contracts</label>
            </p>  
            </div>
    </div>

    <div id="container" class="items">
         <div class="Newcontracts vcf-actus item">
             <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                 <div class="vcf-img">
                     <span>background</span>
                     <img src="" alt="Image">
                 </div>
                 <div class="vcf-text">
                     <span>Mathematics</span>
                     <h4></h4>
                     <span class="vcf-date"></span>
                     <p>Curabitur volutpat laoreet sapien eu mattis. Vestibulum volutpat erat vel     vestibulum mollis. ...</p>
                 </div>
             </a>
         </div>
    </div>
```

this works fine, but what i want is to load dynamicaly the content of div filters and div items too then build checkboxs and items to filter from a SharePoint list by REST calls.

i did all of that and it works fine but now the little filtering function is not working any more since the filtering checkboxs are loaded after it despite i added the magic function ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded but the browser is still loading the filtering function before the total loading of checkboxs.

can you help me with this one please,  thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: `$(document).on('click', 'div.filters input:checkbox', function () {})`